# Appcelerator: No Android SDKs were found under the specified SDK location, with Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, windows-10, appcelerator

I first installed Android Studio .
then Downloaded Android SDK in a separate  folder C:/Users/user-name/SDKs 
pointed out Android Studio to this Directory and it went just fine.

Then Installed Appcelerator Studio and it went just fine .
Studio wanted to download Android SDK to a specific location .here i pointed the SDK locatioon to the Directory C:/Users/user-name/SDKs

And here the error Comes ,No Android SDKs were found under the specified SDK location

PS : when i click manage AVDs it pops up Android AVD manager !! 
Using Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Direct answer for this Question : 
go to C:/Users/user-name/.titanium/
delete the file named config.json 
then restart the IDE

This should solve the problem instantly

on Windows 10

Comment: in that case, it appears the config wasn't properly saved. Perhaps a bug in Appcelerator Studio

Comment: i noticed that lots of people facing it on windows .so i tended to make a question and answer it myself

Comment: I have the issue on Mac. What should i do then?